# Hide HTML form until action is performed

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I am using a checkbox to hide/unhide a form.

The code below does this correctly, but I need the form to be hidden at first and only show once the checkbox is checked.

EDIT: As requested, the post contains the full HTML. I debugged removing all other css / crispy forms / template extensions etc. to no avail.

`html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

  {% block body_block %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/regressionBuilder.css' %}">

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function enableRegressionBuilder(){
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("buildPIT");
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
            document.getElementById("regressionBuilder").style.display="block";
          }
        else{
            document.getElementById("regressionBuilder").style.display="none";
      }
    }
  </script>


    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="buildPIT" onChange="enableRegressionBuilder();">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="buildPIT">Build PIT</label>
    </div>


      <form class="form" id="regressionBuilder" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form2|crispy }}

        <input class = "btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="buildRegression" value="CALCULATE" >
      </form>


  {% endblock %}
```

This works but the following `css` is supposed to hide the form initially, which is not happening:

```
#regressionBuilder {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Can you update the question to include a complete example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: this might be heppening because for some reason your checkbox brings always true back so your JS overrides the initial css. Or your css is not included.

Comment: **Unrelated to the issue:** [checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) is a boolean property. You do not have to compare it to other booleans. `if(checkBox.checked){` would suffice. Furthermore your `else` operation should be `.style.display=""` to default back to the css definition.

Comment: The logic of this code seems to be correct, can you show us the HTML you are using?

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas thanks but no, I deactivated JS and still the ```display:none``` does not hide the form (or any ```input``` element for that matter)

Comment: @David after restarting my machine the problem disappeared, so it must have been a cache issue. How can I close/delete the question as it is no longer relevant?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this working example which is similar to your code.

```js
function showForm(){
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("checkbox");
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
     document.getElementById("form1").style.display="block";
    }
   else{
     document.getElementById("form1").style.display="none";
      }
    }
```

```css
#form1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h3>Hide/Show</h3>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="showForm()" id="checkbox"/>
<div id="form1">
  Form
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic does work, the problem might be in your css file, maybe a selector with a higher specificity overriding your css rule.

here is a slightly different version of your code which is working fine.

```js
showForm = () => {
    checkbox.checked
        ? form1.style.display="block"
        : form1.style.display="none";
}
```

```css
#form1 { display:none; }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" onclick="showForm()">
<form action="" id="form1"> The Form </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have something that overrides your `display: none` class. You don't need javascript really, if you just put your form inside the same div container as the checkbox.

```css
input#buildPIT ~ form#regressionBuilder {
  display: none  
}

#buildPIT:checked ~ #regressionBuilder {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="buildPIT">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="buildPIT">Build PIT</label>

  <form class="form" id="regressionBuilder" method="post">
    <input class = "btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="buildRegression" value="CALCULATE" >
  </form>
</div>
```